# Microsoft Bot State data store to SQL Server database using C#

Tags: c#, botframework

How to store the bot state data to a SQL Server database? I have this code which performs form flow action and collects user inputs. These data I need to save it to database and show the user with a Request ID for future reference. As I'm new to these things, got struck on this stage.

Below is the code I'm working on.

```
// Hardware
public enum HardwareOptions
{
    Mouse, Printer, Keyboard, Monitor
};

[Serializable]
public class HardwareQuery
{
    [Prompt("Choose your {&} ? {||}")]
    public HardwareOptions? Hardware;

    [Prompt("Please enter {&}")]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    [Prompt("Please enter {&}")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [Prompt("Please provide your business need / {&} below")]
    public string Justification { get; set; }

    public static IForm<HardwareQuery> BuildForm()
    {
        return new FormBuilder<HardwareQuery>()
                .Message("Welcome to the PHI Create Hardware Request!")
                .Build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bot Framework SDKv4:

[As written here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) you need to implement the IStorage interface.

You can take the example I made [here](https://gist.github.com/liamkernighan/79a7939d72f426d0b0393adab9cca6f4) as a blueprint.

Comment: Could you please help here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600620/how-to-fetch-data-from-sql-server-by-using-luis-and-azure-bot-service

Answer (score 0):

> How to store the bot state data to a SQL Server database?

The Azure Extensions allow us to [store bot's state data in Azure SQL](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/AzureSql), you can install and use it with you bot application. Besides, if you’d like to implement/customize BotDataStore with your own SQL server database, you can check [the sourc code of Azure Extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/SqlBotDataStore.cs) on GitHub to know how to implement the `IBotDataStore` interface in order to use a SQL database.

> These data I need to save it to database and show the user with a Request ID for future reference.

If you just want to save the user inptes that you collect from `HardwareQuery` Form, you can get user inputs and save into database on completion method.

```
public static IForm<HardwareQuery> BuildForm()
{
    return new FormBuilder<HardwareQuery>()
            .Message("Welcome to the PHI Create Hardware Request!")
                .OnCompletion(async (context, HardwareQueryForm) =>
                {
                    //you code logic 

                    string hardware = HardwareQueryForm.Hardware.ToString();
                    string details = HardwareQueryForm.Details;
                    int quantity = HardwareQueryForm.Quantity;
                    string justification = HardwareQueryForm.Justification;

                    //connect to database and save user inputs into database
                })
                .Build();
}
```