# How to fetch data from SQL Server by using LUIS and Azure Bot Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I'm new to BOT and my use case is : I'm trying to create a Bot using Azure bot framework. Which will get some relevant information for user from SQL Server DB hosted in Azure, based on some analysis. Also, I need to integrate this Bot with Azure App service. Right now I'm trying this,
used Microsoft Azure bot framework to create a Bot. When I'm hitting the url

```
     https://testbot1.azurewebsites.net/api/messages
```

its showing message "Upgrade to WebSocket is required." in the browser.

I know some problem with my understanding. However, at the same time I would like to know, is there any step by step approach for my use case ? Any tutorial from Microsoft or link will help? Thanks.

Comment: Open the bot framework documentation, create your bot via C#, node.js or Python. Run it on your localhost, share it via ngrok, save your temporary ngrok address to Azure (you should add a new self-hosted bot to your Azure account) then try to type something to your bot via Skype or Telegram.

Comment: MS provided documents are not enough for this usecase

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Storage.EntityFramework & https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5716. As for the WebSocket error, what do you see when you click on the All App service option under App Service settings of the bot?